# Java and Gradle using build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I have a question concerning the build process of using build.gradle

If you have a dependency

`implementation "com.company.div:oauth2-client:1.0.0"`

If the above is in the build.gradle shouldn't the command `./gradlew build` include that dependency before building the code?

I am using Eclipse with spring-tool-suite and for my new TokenUtils none of the imports are getting resolved.

`import com.company.dev.oauth2.oauth2...`  // Not getting resolved.

Comment: Doesn't `implementation` mean it's on the runtime path, but not compile time?

Comment: Dave Newton, I am performing some outside research to find the answer to that question.  I do not know.

Comment: Please show your **build.gradle** file. Without this, everything is a guessing game...

Comment: No, if you want to "use" the library in your code, this is correct. See: [Gradle DOCs - Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph)

Comment: @SimpleJack thank you for replying.  Due to policy I cannot post the build.gradle file :(  (Sorry have to feed the family).  However, your reply with See: Gradle DOCs - Java Plugin I am researching.

Comment: @DaveNewton In standard Gradle, `implementation` means it's on the path at compile-time and run-time. For compile-time only dependencies, there's `compileOnly`, and for run-time only dependencies, there's `runtimeOnly`. There's also test versions of those configurations, and `api` stuff (the link in SimpleJack's comment goes into more detail).

Comment: @Moojjoo After adding that dependency, assuming it was added correctly, has Eclipse refreshed the project (manually or automatically) so that it knows that dependency is available?

Comment: @Slaw I have built and rebuilt and closed all IDE(s); BASH windows even restarted my system and it does not seem like the dependency is being pulled in.  I would expect the same.  I am actually taking an awesome course on Udemy where the instructor is using Maven instead of Gradle and he would simply click the Maven refresh and the project would update with the dependencies.

Comment: @Slaw Hm I reversed it in my head; while remembering all this I also came across the Baeldung post on this, which seems completely incorrect, or I’m misreading it.

Comment: Surely you can post a *different* build.gradle which doesn't contain any company secrets but shows the same problem? See [mre]